# What does %[^\n] mean in C?

Tags: c, string

What does `%[^\n]` mean in C? 
I saw it in a program which uses `scanf` for taking multiple word input into a string variable. I don't understand though because I learned that scanf can't take multiple words.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char line[100];
    scanf("%[^\n]",line);
    printf("Hello,World\n");
    printf("%s",line);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's called a _scan set_ in the documentation for [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html)
et al.

Comment: Common problems with `scanf("%[^\n]",line);`  1) It does not limit input, so in this case, input text 100 characters or more can overflow the `line[]` buffer. 2) If the _first_ character encountered is a `'\n'`, _nothing_ is changed about `line[]` and the function returns 0.  3) The `'\n'` remains in `stdin`.  Save yourself future problems, do not use `scanf("%[^\n]",line);`  Research and use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: In C, `%[^\n]` has no meaning.  In the scanf formatting language (which is used by C) it means that your code has opened a very large vulnerability to an overflow exploit.   Learning the scanf formatting language is *not* learning C.  Indeed, doing so is an impediment to learning C.

Comment: When you "learned that scanf can't take multiple words", that referred to the `%s` flag. In your code above, you're using `%[`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`[^\n]` is a kind of regular expression.

- `[...]`: it matches a nonempty sequence of characters from the *scanset* (a set of characters given by `...`).
- `^` means that the scanset is "negated": it is given by its *complement*.
- `^\n`: the scanset is all characters except `\n`.

Furthermore `fscanf` (and `scanf`) will read the longest sequence of input characters matching the format.

So `scanf("%[^\n]", s);` will read all characters until you reach `\n` (or `EOF`) and put them in `s`. It is a common idiom to read a whole line in C.

See also [§7.21.6.2 The fscanf function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html).

Comment: Another thing if we use any other character other then \n will it work same ?

Comment: @SalmanSadi: do you mean something like `scanf("[^a]", s);`? It will read the whole string till the letter `a`.

Comment: @md5 Note that `scanf("[^a]", s);` will not change `s` if the first character to read is `'a'`.  Do not expect `s` to have the value `""` in that case.

Comment: It is kind of regular expression yes, like everything else in scanf is kind of regular expression.

Comment: "It is a common idiom to read a whole line" --> except it fails to read the _whole_ line, leaving the `'\n'` in `stdin`.

Answer (score 8):

`scanf("%[^\n]",line);` is a **problematic** way to read a *line*.  It is worse than [`gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2410359).

C defines *line* as:

> A text stream is an ordered sequence of characters composed into *lines*, each line consisting of zero or more characters plus a terminating new-line character. Whether the last line requires a terminating new-line character is implementation-defined.

The `scanf("%[^\n]", line)` has the specifier `"%[^\n]"`.  It scans for unlimited number of characters that match the *scan-set* `^\n`.  If none are read, the specifier fails and `scanf()` returns with `line` unaltered.  If at least one character is read, all matching characters are read and saved and a *null character* is appended.

The scan-set `^\n` implies all character that are *not* (due to the `'^'`) `'\n'`.

---

**`'\n'` is not read**

`scanf("%[^\n]",....` fails to read a *new line character* `'\n'`.  It remains in `stdin`.  The entire *line* is not read.

**Buffer overflow**

The below leads to *undefined behavior*  (UB) should more than 99 characters get read.

```
char line[100];
scanf("%[^\n]",line);  // buffer overflow possible
```

**Does nothing on empty line**

When the line consists of only `"\n"`, `scanf("%[^\n]",line);` returns a `0` without setting `line[]` - no *null character* is appended.  This can readily lead to *undefined behavior* should subsequent code use an uninitialized `line[]`.  The `'\n'` remains in `stdin`.

**Failure to check the return value**

`scanf("%[^\n]",line);` assumes input succeeded.  Better code would check the `scanf()` return value.

---

**Recommendation**

Do not use `scanf()` and instead use `fgets()` to read a *line* of input.

```
#define EXPECTED_INPUT_LENGTH_MAX 49
char line[EXPECTED_INPUT_LENGTH_MAX + 1  + 1  + 1];
//                                    \n + \0 + extra to detect overly long lines 

if (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
  size_t len = strlen(line);
  // Lop off potential trailing \n if desired.
  if (len > 0 && line[len-1] == '\n') {
    line[--len] = '\0';
  }
  if (len > EXPECTED_INPUT_LENGTH_MAX) {
    // Handle error
    // Usually includes reading rest of line if \n not found.
  }
```

The `fgets()` approach has it limitations too.  e.g. (reading embedded *null characters*).

Handling user input, possible hostile, is challenging.

Answer (score 4):

```
scanf("%[^\n]",line);
```

means: scan till `\n` or an enter key.

Comment: ... or end of input i.e.`CTRL+D`

Answer (score 2):

```
scanf("%[^\n]",line);
```

Will read user input until enter is pressed or a newline character is added (`\n`) and store it into a variable named line.

Answer (score -2):

**Question:** what is %[^\n] mean in C?

1. Basically the `\n` command prints the output in the next line, but in
   case of C gives the `Null` data followed by the above problem only.
2. Because of that to remove the unwanted data or null data, need to add
   Complement/negotiated symbol`[^\n]`. It gives all characters until the next line
   and keeps the data in the defined expression.
3. Means it is the Complemented data or rewritten data from the trash

**EX:**

```
char number[100]; //defined a character ex: StackOverflow
scanf("%[^\n]",number); //defining the number without this statement, the 
character number gives the unwanted stuff `���`
printf("HI\n"); //normaly use of printf statement
printf("%s",number); //printing the output
return 0;
```