# C : trying to remove spaces from a string without using any string library functions

Tags: c, string

So I am trying to figure out a way to print a string without spaces and it is not working for some reason, whenever I enter in a string to the program it ends out printing nothing.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *removeSpaces(char *inString);

int main() {
    char str1[50];
    printf("Enter a string : ");
    scanf("%s", &str1);
    removeSpaces(str1);
}

char *removeSpaces(char *inString) {
    char str2[50];
    int j = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        if (inString[i] != ' ') {
            str2[j] = inString[i];
            j++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        printf("%s", str2[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not use `&` with arrays in scanf ==> `scanf("%49s", str1);`

Comment: In `removeSpaces()` print characters with `printf("%c", str2[i]);`

Comment: `%s` in `scanf()` will look for the next whitespace character and ends the input. Use `%[^\n]`.

Comment: @pmg hey so i tried printing it, it shows the first segment fine but when it reaches the space it prints garbled text

Comment: @Ruks oh cheers man it worked, only problem is it shows a bunch of garbled text beside it

Comment: Change the printing to `for (int i = 0; str2[i] != '\0'; i++) printf("%c", str2[i]);` OR simply get rid of the for loop and  just do `printf("%s", str2);`

Comment: @dankcodez The "garbled" text is due to undefined behavior because your array is uninitialized. Do this: `char str1[50] = {0};` for both the arrays.

Comment: Thanks guys the things you said worked

Comment: @Ruks although i still dont understand what %[^\n] does

Comment: @dankcodez Good reference to read more about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39431924/what-does-n-mean-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Wrong input approach**

Below will not scan into `str1` anything with a space.

```
// bad
char str1[50];
scanf("%s", &str1);
```

Instead, use `fgets()` to read a *line* and form a *string*.

```
char str1[50];
if (fgets(str1, sizeof str, stdin)) {
  // success!
```

Lop off the potential trailing `'\n'` if desired.

```
  str1[strcspn(str1, "\n")] = '\0';
```

**Reads past end of string**

The loops reads to the size of the array.  It should loop to the *null chracter*.

```
// for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
for (int i = 0; inString[i]; i++)
```

**Missing \0**

The string formation in `str2[]` is incomplete as it lacks a *null chracter* `'\0'`.

```
str2[j] = '\0'; // add after the loop
```

**Warnings not fully enabled**

Below should warn about mis-match of `"%s"` with `str2[i]`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    printf("%s", str2[i]);
}
```

Instead, without a loop.

```
 printf("%s", str2);
```

This is the biggest lesson to learn here. By fully enabling warnings, the compiler provides rapid feedback that something is wrong or questionable; faster than Stackoverflow.

**Missing return**

`char *removeSpaces(char *inString)` is expected to return a `char *`, yet code lacks a `return something;`.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use pointers to walk memory locations testing each position for unwanted `char` value,  Here is your function modified to use that method:

```
char *removeSpaces(char *inString);// your original prototype
char *remove_char(char *inString, char c);//generalized  

int main(void) {
    //use suggestions in other answer for correct user input
    const char str1[] = {"this is a string with spaces"};//for simple illustration

    printf("%s\n", removeSpaces(str1));
    printf("%s\n", remove_char(str1, ' '));
    return 0;
}

char *removeSpaces(char *inString)// your original prototype
{
    if(!inString) return (char *)"bad input";
    char *from; // "read" pointer
    char *to; // "write" pointer

    from = to = inString; // init both read and write pointers to original string

    while (*from) 
    { 
        if( (*from != ' ') && (*from != '\t') && (*from != '\n'))
        { 
            *to++ = *from; 
        } 
        from++; 
    } 
    *to = 0; 

    return inString;// add a return statement to return the char *
}

//optionally, create your function to remove any unwanted character
char *remove_char(char *inString, char c)//generalized  
{
    char *from; // "read" pointer
    char *to; // "write" pointer

    from = to = inString; // init both read and write pointers to original string

    while (*from) 
    { 
        if (*from != c) 
        { 
            *to++ = *from; 
        } 
        from++; 
    }  
   *to = 0; 

    return inString;// add a return statement to return the char *
}
```