# When I try to run this code it's gives me no output

Tags: c

I built it when I click to run it's showing no errors no warnings nothing

```
#define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO 1
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char name[20], address[30];
    char c;
    printf("put your pass key: ");
    c = getchar();

    printf("Enter your name: ");
    scanf("%s",name);

    printf("Enter your address: ");
    scanf("%s",address);

    printf("--------------------------\n");
    printf("Entered Name: %s\n",name);
    printf("Entered Address: %s\n",address);

    printf("Your pass key: ");
    putchar(c);
}
```

I tried to run it from pass key point and it works but when I continue it's given me nothing

Comment: I tried it in Repl.it. It runs fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "tried to run it from pass key point"?  How exactly are you running this program?

Comment: Works for me. What input values are you providing?

Comment: Why is pass key just one character? If you type more than 1 character, the rest will be taken as the name.

Comment: You say "no errors no warnings nothing". Do you see the "put your pass key: " prompt? If so, your question needs to tell us exactly what you see, not just what you don't see. And if you're able to provide input to the program, you need to tell us exactly what input you're providing.

Comment: `scanf("%s", name);` will stop at the first whitespace, so only a single-word name can be entered. Similarly `scanf("%s", address);` will take only a single word. If you enter two words for your name, the second will taken as the address.

Comment: i run it on eclipse and it's shows nothing but when using repl like @user366312 it works I don't see anything in console on eclipse

Comment: Do you mean the console closes before you have a chance to see the output? At the end of `main`, put `while(getchar() != 'Q');` and it will wait for you to enter `Q`.

Comment: Please post the *exact* responses to the prompts – by editing the question.

Comment: Duplicate of ~ *scanf leaves newline character in buffer*...?

Comment: What exactly is a *pass key*?

Answer (score 0):

I have compiled you code and it works fine for me. Everything is fine. Maybe the input values provided by you is not in correct format.

Comment: That probably should have been a comment (but others have said pretty much the same thing).

Comment: actually comments and my answer was post almost at the same time. I was just typing and they were just commenting. That's why same thing twice.

Comment: Yet this still does not make an answer. I undertand that you don't have enough repo to write a comment. That is no reason to write an answer instead which does not answer anything instead.

Answer (score 0):

The Code is working perfectly fine.
[Check your results here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMnNM.)

As rng70 said, recheck your input values. Also, if you're adding spaces between your `string` input, it won't work because whitespace acts as a delimiter for `scanf()` by default.

*Sorry to bother!*

To be precise, characters after spaces are not considered as input for `strings`, if that's what your error is.

To solve that problem, you can use `scanf("%[^\n]", name);`

Check [md5's post on this for assistance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39431982/12055031). Thanks.

Comment: The solution is *not enough* if you make the same change to `address` input, where the input buffer will already contain the newline entered at the end of `name`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly.

However, under Linux the program would work the following way:

You close your eyes, assume your program works correctly and type. You will see:

```
put your pass key: KMartin
Enter your name: Enter your address: Hello
--------------------------
Entered Name: Martin
Entered Address: Hello
Your pass key: K
```

Why?

When you type some keys in Linux, the operating system will store the keys pressed in some buffer until the "enter" ("return") key is pressed.

Maybe MINGW has the same behaviour.

So the program reaches `getchar()` and I type "K" "M" "a" "r" "t" "i" "n".

Linux stores these keys into a buffer and instead of passing these keys to the program.

I press the "enter" ("return") key. Then Linux will pass the "K" to the `getchar()` function and the remaining keys ("Martin") to the `scanf()` function.

This behaviour can be disabled:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <termios.h>

int main(void) {
    char name[20], address[30];
    char c;
    struct termios tios;

    printf("put your pass key: ");

    /* Disable the buffer */
    tcgetattr(1,&tios);
    tios.c_lflag&=~ICANON;
    tios.c_cc[VTIME]=0;
    tios.c_cc[VMIN]=1;
    tcsetattr(1,TCSANOW,&tios);

    c = getchar();

    /* Re-enable the buffer
     * If the buffer is not enabled,
     * sscanf() won't work correctly. */
    tios.c_lflag|=ICANON;
    tcsetattr(1,TCSANOW,&tios);

    printf("\nEnter your name: ");
    ...
```

... and the output will be:

```
put your pass key: K
Enter your name: Martin
Enter your address: Hello
--------------------------
Entered Name: Martin
Entered Address: Hello
Your pass key: K
```

**EDIT**

> i run it on eclipse and it's shows nothing but when using repl like @user366312 it works I don't see anything in console on eclipse

The consoles in Eclipse typically do not allow input so programs can write output but not receive input.

However, I know that there is some check box (at least in some Eclipse versions) that allow input...

I don't know if you will have the problem I described above when using Eclipse.

However, if you have that behaviour, the `settermios` method probably won't work...