# everything works well except for when i give selection 3 as set dosa, it takes that input as invalid although it isnt

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers, user-defined-functions

These are some variations of the code, the output is the same in all the variations. Ive tried using pointers and also by defining a function caseInsensitiveComparision and also by some minor changes in the logic, in all variations consisting of all combinations of the changes result in the same output-

> 

Enter the number of selections (up to 5): 3
Enter selection 1: idli
Price for idli: Rs15/-
Enter selection 2: tea
Price for tea: Rs15/-
Enter selection 3: set dosa
Selection set not found in the menu.
The total bill payable including GST is: Rs30/-

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

const char items[5][20] = {"TEA", "COFFEE", "IDLI", "SET DOSA", "MASALA DOSA"};
int prices[5] = {15, 20, 15, 30, 40};  // Predefined prices

int findItemIndex(const char *selection) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (strcasecmp(selection, items[i]) == 0) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;  // Return -1 if not found
}

int main() {
    char selections[5][20];  // User inputs for selections
    int numSelections, totalBill = 0;
    
    printf("Enter the number of selections (up to 5): ");
    scanf("%d", &numSelections);

    for (int i = 0; i < numSelections; i++) {
        printf("Enter selection %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%19s", selections[i]);

        int index = findItemIndex(selections[i]);
        if (index != -1) {
            printf("Price for %s: Rs%d/-\n", selections[i], prices[index]);
            totalBill += prices[index];
        } else {
            printf("Selection %s not found in the menu.\n", selections[i]);
        }
    }

    if (totalBill == 0) {
        printf("No valid selections found.\n");
    } else {
        printf("The total bill payable including GST is: Rs%d/-\n", totalBill);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

this is another variation:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int caseInsensitiveCompare(const char str1[], const char str2[]) {
    int i = 0;
    while (str1[i] && str2[i]) {
        if (tolower((unsigned char)str1[i]) != tolower((unsigned char)str2[i])) {
            return 0;  // Not equal
        }
        i++;
    }
    return (str1[i] == '\0' && str2[i] == '\0');
}

const char items[5][20] = {"TEA", "COFFEE", "IDLI", "SET DOSA", "MASALA DOSA"};
int prices[5] = {15, 20, 15, 30, 40};  // Predefined prices

int findItemIndex(const char selection[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (caseInsensitiveCompare(selection, items[i])) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;  // Return -1 if not found
}

int main() {
    char selections[5][20];  // User inputs for selections
    int numSelections, totalBill = 0;
    
    printf("Enter the number of selections (up to 5): ");
    scanf("%d", &numSelections);

    for (int i = 0; i < numSelections; i++) {
        printf("Enter selection %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%19s", selections[i]);

        int index = findItemIndex(selections[i]);
        if (index != -1) {
            printf("Price for %s: Rs%d/-\n", items[index], prices[index]);
            totalBill += prices[index];
        } else {
            printf("Selection %s not found in the menu.\n", selections[i]);
        }
    }

    if (totalBill == 0) {
        printf("No valid selections found.\n");
    } else {
        totalBill += totalBill * 0.18;
        printf("The total bill payable including GST is: Rs%d/-\n", totalBill);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf` using `%s` reads a single word. It stops at whitespace. You could use `" %19[^\n]"` instead. The space before `%` is important. [What does %[^\n] mean in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39431924/what-does-n-mean-in-c) Normally I would recommend `fgets` instead but mixing it with `scanf` is problematic and it includes the newline character that you'd need to remove.

Answer (score 1):

I notice that one of your items has a space: `"MASALA DOSA"`. But you use `%19s` with `scanf`. This will stop reading at the first whitespace, meaning that a user entering `MASALA DOSA` will read `MASALA` into the variable. This will obviously not match any of the values in your array.

To read 19 or fewer characters up to a newline use `%19[^\n]` as your format specifier.